# React Native AsyncStorage: Accessing Value from Promise Object

Tags: react-native, promise

When I use `AsyncStorage.getItem()` to retrieve the value (an email address) of a specified key, it returns a Promise object as indicated in the documentation. The value appears in object like so:

```
{
  _45: 0
  _54: null
  _65: "testuser@test.com"
  _81: 1
}
```

Can I reliably access this value by calling `obj._65` or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 10):

AsyncStorage return a promise. you can use .then for get value

exemple:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('key').then((keyValue) => {
  console.log(keyValue) //Display key value
  }, (error) => {
  console.log(error) //Display error
});
```

Comment: console.log value display value but return value display promise

Comment: When i return it i also get promise.How did you solve it?

Answer (score -2):

Looking [at the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html) you should be able to do this reliably to retrieve data from your async storage object.:

```
try {
  const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@MySuperStore:key');
  if (value !== null){
    // We have data!!
    console.log(value._65);
  }
} catch (error) {
  // Error retrieving data
}
```

you must use this within a function that is `async` however or you will get a runtime exception.